# How to: Markdown PDF align table to the left

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc, tex

**Goal**
I have been wanting to create a pdf reporting function but I have not been able to restyle the layout of the pdf as I would like to. One of the issues I am addressing is that I am not able to align the table to the left. Right now it is centred in the middle.

**System and others**

- CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
- TeX 3.141592 (Web2C 7.5.6)

**template.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Reporting"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(head(cars), format = "markdown") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, position = "left")
```
````

**build_report.R**

```
# Libraries
require(knitr)
require(markdown)
library(RMySQL)
library(png)
library(kableExtra)

# create .md file
knit("template.Rmd", "template.md")

# create .html file
markdownToHTML("template.md", "template.html", options=c("use_xhml"))

# create .pdf file
command <- paste0("pandoc -V geometry:'left=0.5in,bottom=1in,top=1.5in' -s ", "template.html", " -o ", "output.pdf")
system(command)
```

**output.pdf**
Output example (irrelevant info left out)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfIw0.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Able to solve it with help of @Hao

1) From .Rmd to .md straight to PDF, leaving out markdownToHTML()

2) Including library(kableExtra) in **template.Rmd** not in **build_report.R**

3) Using format = "markdown"

**template.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Reporting"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(head(cars), format = "markdown") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, position = "left")
```
````

**build_report.R**

```
# Libraries
require(knitr)
require(markdown)
library(RMySQL)
library(png)
library(kableExtra)

# create .md file
knit("template.Rmd", "template.md")

# create .pdf file
command <- paste0("pandoc -V geometry:'left=0.5in,bottom=1in,top=1.5in' -s ", "template.md", " -o ", "output.pdf")
system(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `format = "markdown"` in `kable` and put `library(kableExtra)` somewhere

Comment: The library was included in the build_report.R. I forgot to add this part in this example. I have added it now. I have removed the `format = "markdown"` but the table remains to be centered.

Comment: @Andrie I actually can't understand what you are trying to do. In the rmd file, you set the format to be pdf_document while in the r file, it seems like you try to render a md first and then convert it to html?

Comment: Thats correct. I apologize as I am not too familiar with this. I based this approach on a tutorial. I basically want to generate a pdf report and so the approach which was suggested was: Rmd > md > html > pdf

Comment: @Andrie you can generate pdf document from rmarkdown directly. If you are using rstudio, it's as simple as clicking the render button on top. If you are using it in terminal, just use the render function in rmarkdown